# Update Activity on closing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity A. Once A has been loaded, on clicking a button in A adds a fragment F on A's home Layout. Now once inside F, if i am calling`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`, which infacts navigates again into the Activity A. Is there any way  I can actually make some changes in the activity A once the fragment has been popbackstacked? I don't know which method is called in the activity once the fragment has been popbackstacked and you have your activity. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add OnBackStackChangedListener(). Just do something like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener()
{
    public void onBackStackChanged() 
    {                   

    }
});
```

This callback will be called after each change on the back stack.

Comment: where to call this method? @R. Adasiewicz

Comment: I am not adding the fragments to backstack during adding it. I wrote  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

Comment: Just call this in onCreate() inside your Activity

Comment: yes, but I have not added the fragments to backstack because of some issues. In that case what to do?

Answer (score 1):

create and implement an interface in your activity

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
OnFragmentCloseListener mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnFragmentCloseListener {
    public void onClosed(Bundle data);
}

//call this while closing the fragment
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putExtra("key"," value");
mCallback.onClosed(data);

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnFragmentCloseListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentCloseListener ");
    }
}

}
```

In Your activity

```
  public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements MyFragment.OnFragmentCloseListener {

   public void onClosed(Bundle data) {
    //get the budle data here
   }
}
```

Comment: @SaravInfern- what to do in case of multiple fragments and if all of them are going to share some datas with the activity?

Comment: Have a common interface and in the bundle put a key to indicate which fragment it is from `Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putExtra("from"," fragment1");
mCallback.onClosed(data);` and in the activity check the key to know which is being closed